# Can I define RADIUS clients with Python?

Tags: python, radius, freeradius

I wrote an auth module for FreeRADIUS with Python.
I want to manage a NAS with it.

Is there way except generating a client.conf file and restarting?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly no. You can use sqlite if you want an easily modifiable local data store for clients definitions.

Comment: Can freeradius load clients from sql base or plugin?

Comment: Or i need to provide conf file to it?

Comment: It can load clients from sql using the sqlite driver. Just set `read_clients = yes` in your SQL config. You'll probably want to use FreeRADIUS 3.x.x